# Градиент фона сайта.

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Не подскажете, как фон страницы залить вертикальным градиентом? И еще вопрос. Форматирую параметры текста, заданные в css, но они не хотят меняться. Чем менять, чтобы наверняка? Я <basefont>-ом пыталась.

Answer (score 6):

css3 (для поддержки старых браузеров используй полоску грдиента с repeat-x)

```
body {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f4f4f4), to(red));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, red);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, red);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, red);
}
```

По поводу шрифтов, то тут 2 варианта:

1. неправильно записан селектор;
2. используется стиль который перекрывает твои, в этом случае после свойства указывай через пробел `!important` (например, `color: #992200 !important;`)

Answer (score 1):

**RedMonkey** всё правильно указал, но я хотел бы дополнить, что
если вы беспокоитесь о кроссбраузерности, то использование линейного градиента -
это не есть гуд. А вообще, [подробно почитать можно в этой статье](http://htmlbook.ru/css3-na-primerakh/lineinyi-gradient)

Answer (score 0):

Вопросов как Ваш, по новым средствам/возможностям/утилитам море. Для многих вопросов есть универсальные решения. Например сервисы. Как [этот](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), который позволяет визуально редактировать градиент, видеть результат и гибко настраивать, в соответствии с правилами (референсом). Есть css-фреймворки, которые упрощают подобного вида задачи, сокращают возможное количество ошибок. Всем советую - мой любимый фреймвор [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/). Смотрите, с чем лучше уживётесь:)